# setState One State of an Object in a Mapping Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components, react-component

I've been dealing with this issue for two days. Couldn't find a solution online and at this point I think I'm doing something wrong.

So the point of this app is to click the button and drop an apple. Clicking the button changes tree's state and classname in the component causing it to shake. And Sass animation does the rest. But I can't change one apple's classname. And therefore, cannot animate one apple. It just changes all of them I think and they kinda overlap on top of each other. Which is not what I wanted.

Don't know if I'm handling the process wrong but here's the code for app.js:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      apples: [],
      treeState: ''
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.setState(
      {
        apples: [
      {
        id: '1',
        status: 'present'
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        status: 'present'
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        status: 'present'
      }
    ],
  treeState: 'stagnant'});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">        
        <div className="App-header">
        <img onClick={this.shakeTree.bind(this)} className="grab" alt="grab"/>
          <Apples apples={this.state.apples}/>
          <Tree treeState ={this.state.treeState}/>              
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  shakeTree() {
    var css = (this.state.treeState === "stagnant") ? "shaking" : "stagnant";
    this.setState({"treeState":css}); 
    this.dropApples();
}

  dropApples(){
      let apple;
      var random = 2;
      if(this.state.apples){
        apple = this.state.apples.map(applemon => {   
          if(applemon.id==random){
            this.setState(
              {
                apples: [
              {
                id: random, 
                status: 'falling'
              }
            ]});
          }              
        });  
    }
  }  
}

export default App;
```

What I want is to change one of the apples' status to 'falling' without affecting the others. For example, get the apple with id of 2 and change it's status to 'falling'.

Can you please walk through me how or point me some exact resources about how it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't updating the state correctly. You should return the entire updated object to setState

```
dropApples(){
      let apple;
      var random = 2;
      if(this.state.apples){
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            apples: prevState.apples.map(apple => {
                if (apple.id == random) return {...apple, status: 'falling'}
                return apple
            })
        })) 
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel so good right now. Thank you so much! It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

on dropApples, do this to set status to falling for the random apple

```
this.setState({
    apples: this.state.apples.map(
        apple => apple.id === random ? { ...apple, status: 'falling' } : apple
})
```

As an aside: setState is asynchronous, so when you make multiple calls to setState, it may have not committed the previous call and therefore cause inconsistencies.

Comment: Ah, it didn't work. That side note is super helpful though. Thanks! Shubham's answer was the right solution.